# Union of two locally compact space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{R^2}$ and let

$$A=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(x,y):x>0\}\subseteq X\;.$$

Notice that there is no compact set around $\{(0,0)\}$ because it will be open set. It looks like work for example of two locally compact space whose union are not locally compact. Is it true?

Comment: To write $\{\}$ please type `\{\}`

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: Just note that compact sets can be open in general (example, consider space $\{*\}$ with any topology) - openness is a proper of a subset inside a topological space, while compactness is a property of an abstract topological space Y (here I am mean "abstract" in the sense that Y doesn't need to be thought of with an inclusion into another in order to talk of $Y$ being compact). However, once you fix this you will be correct.

Comment: I misunderstood you. Could you clarify your comment again? What by fixing this?

Comment: Thank prof Brian M.Scott for editing my question.What is your comments about it. Dose work good?

Comment: Why should anyone assume the union of two locally compact sets would be locally compact?  So, yes, it looks like you have found an example where this wouldn't be true.